# Add/Remove rows in Lightning Flow builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, visual-workflow, lightning-flow-builder

I am trying to achieve Add/Remove Rows in Lightning Flow.Currently I have added Add/Remove rows as Lightning Component in flow .But with this component users have to hit save button to save records.Is there a way to achieve this without hitting Save button like Finish button act like Save button.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when your component implements the `lightning:availableForFlowScreens` interface you gain access to some Flow controls via an attribute called `v.availableActions`. Rather inconveniently, this is a List you must iterate to get available actions like so:

```
var availableActions = component.get('v.availableActions');
for (var i = 0; i < availableActions.length; i++) {
    if (availableActions[i] == "FINISH") {
        //just to set that the next button is a FINISH button
        component.set('v.complete',true); 
    }
}
```

Then use can remove the footer from the flow and use your Save button to control the flow via the `v.navigateFlow` attribute:

```
onClickNext : function(component,event,helper){
    if (component.get('v.complete')){
        var navigate = component.get("v.navigateFlow");
        navigate("FINISH");
    } else{
         var navigate = component.get("v.navigateFlow");
         navigate("NEXT");
    }
},
```

Optionally, you can use that `v.complete` attribute to change the Text in the button (Next vs Complete)